# How can I prevent the value from being updated in Jquery UI Spinner?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, spinner

I don't want the value of my spinner to be updated when the user clicks on the up arrow.
In the API says:

> spin( event, ui )
>
> Triggered during increment/decrement (to determine direction of spin
>   compare current value with ui.value). Can be canceled, preventing the
>   value from being updated.

But does not show an example of how to do it. 
I started a code like this:

```
var spinner = $( ".mySpinner" ).spinner({
    min: 0,
    spin: function( event, ui ) {
       //don't know what to do!
    }
});​
```

How can I cancel the spin event?

Can you help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Event cancellation in jQuery UI works the same way as for native DOM events.

You only have to call [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/):

```
var spinner = $( ".mySpinner" ).spinner({
    min: 0,
    spin: function( event, ui ) {
       // Cancel the spin event. The value will not be updated.
       event.preventDefault();
    }
});​
```

You can also return `false` from the handler, however this not only cancels the event but effectively stops its propagation to ancestor elements, as if [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation) was called.